# Return window.close() from bottle?

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I am trying to close the current tab/window by returning the following from bottle:

```
@route('/configure', method='POST')
def configure():

    #do other things here...

    return '''<script>window.close();</script>
      <p>You can close this window if it does not automatically close.</p>'''
```

But it does not work. How to make it automatically close?

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect the user to a page that has that as a template. It is best practice for POST handlers. See [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for more information.

Comment: The PRG link is about preventing double form submission when user hits refresh. If I close the page, this does not apply, right?

Comment: I tried to redirect to another function where I return template("<script>window.close();</script>\n"), but it did not work -- did not close the window.